# Scan from scanner and directly print to another printer (2 devices)

Tags: scripts, printing, scanner, automatic

I have a Canon PIXMA MFP that can duplex scan a stack with its document feeder.  I have a separate Brother Duplex Laserprinter.

The Canon is over WiFi and can scan easily with the Simple Scan application.  The Brother printer is over USB and prints fine.

The Canon is an Inkjet printer.  Therefore I would rather not make large copies of files using the inkjet because the laser printer is more efficient and faster.

For now, we scan documents as PDF's from the Canon.  And print the PDF on the Brother.

I would like to take this PDF step out of the process and be able to Scan from Canon and print to the Brother.

So in pseudo-commands : `scan Canon | print Brother`

Is this possible to automate?  I know the simple-scan app can print from the GUI but I don't see printing options from command line.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I believe is in this site:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1726874

basically on the server you will have a directory that you place the PDF files in after they are scanned, and on a regular basis using cron, they will be printed.

How often you set the cron job to run will determine how long after the file is placed in the folder it takes to print.  I hope this helps

Chris

Comment: This is ok, but I'm still ending up scanning as PDF first.  And I'm not sure how to define how many copies of the scan to print.  We print dozens of copies of stacks.  The PDF scanning and then the printing of the PDF is the part I want to skip.  I basically want to put a stack on my Canon scanner, and say "make 50 copies" and then it's all scanned from the Canon and printed to the Brother automatically with no files leftover when the job is done.

Comment: I don't like to promote things, but you may be looking at having to contact a commercial company to get this done. there is a , I don't want to call it a program, but that is basically what it is called fiery, you can find info on it here http://www.efi.com/resources/fiery-how-to-guides-and-docs/fiery-system-10/  This system is sold with/given to you when you purchase certain large scale printers/scanners.  It could be a good project to see if you can start an opensource version of, but as of now I don't know of any.

Answer (score 0):

scanimage   will send the output to standard output in a variety of formats, but probably not a PDF.

If you can get it into a PDF format, then lpr can handle it.
so

```
    scanimage --format pnm  |   unknown program to convert pnm to pdf | lpr
```

I can't experiment with what your doing.  I'd suggest installing sane if you don't already have it.